# Восстановление и удаление bitrix

Tags: php, mysql, битрикс, восстановление, удаление

У меня истек срок пробной версии битрикс.

1. Как его можно удалить? (в Панели управления -> Удаление программ нет 1С битрикса).
2. У меня стоял сайт на пробной версии. Как **установить** bitrix **из архива** business-encode.zip так чтобы не потерять данные для сайта?

На [Установке битрикса](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LmgxfPgmcCg) не показано, как устанавливать из архива (показано как устанавливать с помощью скрипта bitrixsetup.php).

Answer (score 0):

Для удаления старой версии битрикс нужно удалить папку bitrix из проекта и все.

Answer (score 0):

**Установка Битрикса в общем случае состоит из 3 шагов:**

1. скопируйте скрипты сайта в document_root вебсервера. Обычно это папки public_html или www.
2. создайте базу, пользователя базы, дайте доступ пользователю к базе и загрузите в базу дамп.
3. пропишите имя базы, имя пользователя базы и пароль пользователя базы в конфигах битрикса. Это файлы `/bitrix/php_interface/dbconn.php` или `/bitrix/.settings.php` в зависимости от версии битрикса.

**Удаление битрикса** заключается в удалении скриптов из document_root и удаления базы данных.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы планируете пользоваться сайтом далее, то просто купите лицензию и активируйте ключ, сайт заработает. Если хотите установить новую пробную версию Битрикса и продолжать дальше работать со своим сайтом (типа будет бесплатно и бесконечно), то это возможно, но геморройно, требует знаний запросов к базам данных, простых манипуляций с архивами, структуру Битрикса. Ну или Вы просто решили отложить разработку и продолжить "потом", а после истечения срока активации лицензии после истечения пробной версии, сайт станет "недоступным совсем".

Чтобы Ваши наработки сохранить, надо к себе скопировать или заархивировать все папки сайта, кроме папки `bitrix/`, но все же папку `bitrix/templates/*` тоже скопировать, если в ней есть какие-то данные. Также надо сделать копию базы данных. Все это можно осуществить штатным инструментом Битрикса "резервное копирование". Он упакует физические файлы и базу данных.

При разворачивании сайта из архива, если срок пробной версии истек, чтобы восстановить сайт, понадобится установленная версия Битрикса (пробная или активированная). Из архива сайта (вы указали файл business-encode.zip) перезаписываете все файлы кроме папки bitrix/, bitrix/templates/ можно тоже перезаписать. Потом уже с помощью команд и запросов к базе данных восстанавливать из дампа отдельные настройки/инфоблоки и т.д. - это уже надо знать и понимать структуру mysql и таблиц для сайта для разных модулей. Тут уже попотеть придется.

Также, если Вы честный разработчик и являетесь Партнером-разработчиком Битрикс, то можно связаться с ними и попросить продлить срок пробной версии, по причине того, что не успели сделать разработку.

Еще можно штатными инструментами сделать импорт/экспорт инфоблоков в новую установленную пробную версию, а файлы сайта (структуру) скопировать из старой пробной версии. При этом настройки сайта, главного модуля и других модулей нужно будет повторить на новой пробной версии.